# parse data using GSON with ContentValues and ContentProvider

Tags: android, json, gson, android-contentprovider

I am getting data from server in a `JSON` format and I am using `GSON` library to parse the data. my whole mobile database is deigned using content provider and cursor loader.

Now I want to know that how can I parse `JSON` data using `GSON` so that I can directly insert into database using `ContentValues`. Mostly in `GSON` we create model and `GSON` will deserialize data into that model class directly.

So is there any way where `GSON` directly parse data into `ContentValues`

Comment: No you cant. When you use GSON it will give you a model object. Using getters and setters set and get ContentValues.

Comment: Yes you can... You have to write custom (de)serializer

Comment: how to write custom de-serializer ?